# Forcing inline-block elements not to wrap (relatively to each other)

Tags: html, css

I have two `div`s containing text, that I want to display next to each other (like table cells). But if the parent `div` is not wide enough, they appear below each other.

What I want :

```
+------------------+------------------+
|                  |  Some Long text  |
|  Some short text |  Some Long text  |
|                  |  Some Long text  |
+------------------+------------------+
```

What I get :

```
+------------------+
|                  |
|  Some short text |
|                  |
+------------------+---------------------------+
| Some Long text Some Long text Some Long text |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

If I force the second `div`'s width, I get the result that I want, but I want it to take all the remaining width. How can I do that ?

```html
<div style="width: 300px; border: solid 1px;">
  <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; background-color: cyan;">
    Some short text
  </div>
  <!-- if I set 'width: 150px' below, I get what I want -->
  <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; background-color: green;">
    Some long text. Some long text. Some long text.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to define a width, or almost a max-width. If not, it grows till the end of the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the display of both divs to table-cell instead of inline-block:

```html
<div style="width: 300px; border: solid 1px;">
  <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell; background-color: cyan;">
    Some short text
  </div>
  <!-- if I set 'width: 150px' below, I get what I want -->
  <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell; background-color: green;">
    Some long text. Some long text. Some long text.
  </div>
</div>
```